# Argument for an $\epsilon$ free LL(1) grammar being in LR(0)?

Tags: parsers, lr-k

I am trying to understand the reason as given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70733701/2277550)

> If an ε-free grammar is not LR(0), then there is some state with both a shift and a reduce
> action. Since the grammar is ε-free, that state was reached by way of a shift or a goto. The previous state must then have had two different productions with the same FIRST set, contradicting the LL(1) condition.

I don't understand why the previous state would have two different productions with the same FIRST set. Also why would it be a shift-reduce error? Why can't it be reduce-reduce?

Here's what I figured out. The right-hand side of the two items that cause the shift-reduce or reduce-reduce error, would have a series of common terms. That would necessarily imply that

1. The two non-terminals have the same FIRST, if the RHS of the two items are the same.
2. That some non-terminal is left recursive. If the RHS of one item is part of the RHS of the other item.

Both of these would imply that the grammar is not LL(1)? Is that correct?

Comment: @rici Hi, Sorry abt that. I've corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

If $A\to\epsilon ~or~ A\to.$ is the only $\epsilon$-production in $I_0$ state creates always shift-reduce conflict because $A\to\epsilon ~or~ A\to.$ is already reduced in $I_0$ state and any production like $A\to.a$ in $I_0$  creates shift-reduce conflict in initial state  $I_0.$

If more than one $\epsilon$-production $(~like~ B\to\epsilon ~or~ B\to.)$ is present  in  $I_0$ state then you get redce-reduce conflict because they are already reduced in one state.